# MVC C# Lambda Join one to many select one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I need to join 2 table to list class DisplayProductList

```
public class DisplayProductList
{
    public Product_Details Product_Details { get; set; }
    public string Image_Path { get; set; }

    public DisplayProductList()
    {
        Product_Details = new Product_Details();
        Image_Path = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Table

1. Product_Details
2. Product_Images

1 **Product_Details** have many **Product_Images**
But i need to select first record of **Product_Images** to join

```
List<DisplayProductList> displayProductLists = new List<DisplayProductList>();
displayProductLists = db.Product_Details
    .Join(db.Product_Images.OrderBy(o => o.Product_Image_Seq),
    pd => pd.Product_Id,
    pi => pi.Product_Id,
    (pd, pi) => new { pd, pi })
    .Select(s => new DisplayProductList()
        {
            Product_Details = s.pd,
            Image_Path = s.pi.Product_Image_Path
        }).ToList();
```

This is my command. How to change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two variants.

**FirstOrDefault** in projection

```cs
var displayProductLists = db.Product_Details
    .Select(pd => new DisplayProductList()
    {
        Product_Details = pd,
        Image_Path = db.Product_Images
            .Where(pi => pi.Product_Id == pd.Product_Id)
            .OrderBy(pi => pi.Product_Image_Seq)
            .Select(pi => pi.Product_Image_Path)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .ToList();
```

And more closer to the SQL:

```cs
var query = 
    from pd in db.Product_Details
    from pi in db.Product_Images
        .Where(pi => pi.Product_Id == pd.Product_Id)
        .OrderBy(o => o.Product_Image_Seq)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DisplayProductList
    {
        Product_Details = pd,
        Image_Path = pi.Product_Image_Path
    };

var displayProductLists = query.ToList();
```